# Why accented character messes up alignment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, accents

I want two miniboxes side to side, for my CV. I notice the one on the right is a bit off, despite both having (almost) the same format and number of lines.

The "only" difference, I thought, is that the left one uses three "hard" line breaks (paragraphs), whereas the one on the right uses one paragraph over three lines.

However, when I was constructing the MWE, I discovered that the actual problem is from the accented character `É` which moves the text on the left box a bit down.

How can I make the two be perfectly aligned ?

[image: Minimal working example image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}        % use modern latin fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8 bit output font encoding with more glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % so you can type 
\usepackage[margin=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}        % to remove space after section


\titleformat{\section}          % what to format
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}  % how to format the text
  {\thesection}                 % what label to use (number)
  {1em}                         % how much space after label
  {#1}                          % code before the text; #1 is the text
  [{\titlerule[1pt]}]           % code after the text
% \titlespacing*{\command}{left}{before}{after}[right]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0.3em}


\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}  % less space after paragraph
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  % avoid auto indentation
\pagestyle{empty}            % Produces empty heads and feet - no page numbers


%% ============================================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\section*{Education}
  \textbf{École Awesome University 2}\par
  MSc BlaBla -- 0.0 avg. -- 2018\par
  BlaBla Bla Bla Bla

  \bigbreak
  \textbf{École Awesome University 1}\par
  BSc TraLaLa -- 110\% avg. -- 2016\par
  Latex \& stuff plus some other stuff -- Top 5
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
  \section*{Personal}
  \hspace{1.5em} I am super motivated to learn why this two miniboxes are unaligned. This introduction should have about three lines, to look nicely.\par

  \bigbreak
  \textbf{I can:} Duuh\par
  \textbf{Languages:} English -- ok \quad | \quad Latex -- meh\par
  \textbf{Availability:} in the future
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is titlesec. It redefines section in a way that it changes the spacing. Imho the easiest to get around it is to use a \vphantom (the \tikz are only there to show the alignment):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}        % use modern latin fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8 bit output font encoding with more glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % so you can type
\usepackage[margin=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}        % to remove space after section


\titleformat{\section}          % what to format
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}  % how to format the text
  {\thesection}                 % what label to use (number)
  {1em}                         % how much space after label
  {#1}                          % code before the text; #1 is the text
  [{\titlerule[1pt]}]           % code after the text
% \titlespacing*{\command}{left}{before}{after}[right]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0.3em}


\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}  % less space after paragraph
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  % avoid auto indentation
\pagestyle{empty}            % Produces empty heads and feet - no page numbers


%% ============================================================================
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\section*{Education}
  \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(2\textwidth,0);\textbf{École Awesome University 2}\par
  MSc BlaBla -- 0.0 avg. -- 2018\par
  BlaBla Bla Bla Bla

  \bigbreak
  \textbf{École Awesome University 1}\par
  BSc TraLaLa -- 110\% avg. -- 2016\par
  \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(2\textwidth,0);Latex \& stuff plus some other stuff -- Top 5
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
  \section*{Personal}
  \leavevmode\vphantom{\textbf{É}}\hspace{1.5em}I am super motivated to learn why this two miniboxes are unaligned. This introduction should have about three lines, to look nicely.\par

  \bigbreak
  \textbf{I can:} Duuh\par
  \textbf{Languages:} English -- ok \quad | \quad Latex -- meh\par
  \textbf{Availability:} in the future
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe it wouldn't work *all* the time, but wouldn't `\strut` do as well here?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Not here. I tried ;-).

Comment: thanks.  would be interesting to know why.  (strut redefined somewhere?  or strut actually too tall?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The bold É is a bit higher (9.95354pt) than a \strut (9.51996pt). So the bold É pushes the line more down.